# intermediate in javascript looking for a book to learning object oriented programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am an intermediate javaScript programmer, and i am interested in expanding my knowledge in object oriented programming (especially object oriented JavaScript).

I would prefer a book over browsing scattered web resources, does anyone have an idea of which book will be best to get a head start with?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://www.packtpub.com/object-oriented-javascript-applications-libraries/book) published by Packt was an invaluable resource for me recently when I was trying to learn JavaScript's prototype-based system without letting my traditional OO knowledge (Java, etc.) get in the way and make it more confusing.

For a slightly less in-depth treatment, I also recommend [Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](http://apress.com/book/view/159059908x) and John Resig's [Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://apress.com/book/view/1590597273). Both have chapters on the topic.

Comment: +1 - This is one of the better books

Answer (score 2):

It is important to distinguish between *classic* OOP and OO JavaScript.

While some languages such as Java, C# and Python are good for learning OO concepts such as classes, objects, inheritance and polymorphism - JavaScript is not one of those languages.

JavaScript can have object-oriented features but through the use of prototypes. It gets more complicated due to the complex data structures.

I think you should define exactly what you are looking after. If it's learning object-oriented concepts, you should go with a classic OO language to learn the basic concepts, and only then continue on to OOJS.

Answer (score 2):

[Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) by Martin Fowler while the examples are given in Java, the principles behind it are applicable to most OO languages including JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely worth reading: [JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742).

The chapter 5, "Inheritance" covers different types of Object Orientation:

- Pseudoclassical, simulating Class hierarchies by extending prototype objects with new methods
- Prototypal, without classes, using prototype objects to create new instances with common functionalities, then attaching new functions to these new objects directly
- Functional, using constructor functions to create a private scope and return a new object grouping a set of methods with privileged access to the private variables

Comment: Your link goes to the amazon page for *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*, and Crockford is not listed as one of the authors.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I edited my answer to fix the link.

Comment: It's a good book, but I find some the examples willfully complicated.